# Visual Studio 2015 Trava e não volta qunado acesso pagina cshtml e inserido "<"

Tags: .net, mvc, visual-studio, asp

Pessoal esta muito estranho.

Em qualquer projeto quando insiro em um arquivo cshtml um "<" o visual studio 2015 trava e reinicia, isso ocorre em qualquer projeto WEB, ja reinstalei ele 3 vezes e sempre ocorre. So me falta formatar o computador.

Não sei mais o que fazer.

Alguma alma caridosa pode me ajudar.

Comment: Tenta executar isso no cmd/powershell `devenv.exe /resetuserdata`

Comment: Não foi. Não reconhece como comando.

Comment: Tenta rodar no executar (`win` + `R`) ou vá até a pasta que o visual studio está instalado pelo CMD e tente

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este problema já foi reportado pela microsoft está acontecendo porque o `Visual Studio` está vindo sem os `Language Packs` adequados, o download abaixo deve resolver o seu problema:

Download:

https://www.microsoft.com/pt-br/download/details.aspx?id=48157

---

Referências:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32603918/visual-studio-2015-crashes-when-opening-angle-bracket

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32465495/exception-on-opening-existing-project-after-ugrading-to-asp-net-mvc6-beta7

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo.

Comment: Isso é o que da gostar de ser testador, rsrsrsrs

Comment: Tem suas consequências, rsrs

Comment: Se funcionar lembre-se de apontar pra galera qual foi a solução pra resolver seu problema.

Comment: Problema resolvido com a atualização do pacote. Obrigado.

Comment: @NapoleãoMenezes Marca a resposta como correta pra sinalizar os outros membros sobre a efetividade dela

Answer (score 1):

Se for Windows 10, pode ser um bug no proprio SO.
Corrigi o problema quando eu formatei meu computador.

**Se em ultimo caso não der certo, sugiro formatar o computador.**

*Antes, veja se tem alguma atualização pro VS ou Windows.*

Dificil achar esses problemas, visto que tenho vários sistema frameworks aqui.
(MySQL, Node, Python, SQL Server, Oracle, Heroku, Amazon Tools, etc)